# WPF SizeToContent not working when WindowStyle="None"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to remove all chrome (border and title). I can do this however the width does not size correctly.

```
<Window x:Class="ActiveWords.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:ActiveWords.Properties"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
    WindowStyle="ToolWindow"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    AllowDrop="True">
```

I have a small button (50 x 50) as the only content of the Window. When `WindowStyle="None"` the width is too wide, it's about 200. However when I set `WindowStyle="ToolWindow"` both width and height are correct. However I then have a title bar which I don't want.

Any idea how to get this to work please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems really hacky but setting

```
Width="0" Height="0"
```

in the Window should do it.  The SizeToContent should force the window to resize around the button.